# JSSOR Continuous slider displaying 6 from n logos

Tags: jquery, slider, jssor

i'd like to realize a continuous horizontal scroller showing 6 of n thumbnails.
it's for a shop, to display logos of manufacturers.

i am coming from: http://jsfiddle.net/b6qpdyex/3/

with these setting:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: true,
        $PlayOrientation: 1,
        $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear,
        $AutoPlayInterval: 0,
        $SlideDuration: 5500,
        $DisplayPieces: 6
    };
    var manufacturers_scroller = new $JssorSlider$("manufacturers_scroller", options);
});
```

this is my html/smarty code

```
<div class="wrap" id="manufacturers_container">
    <h2>Brauereien</h2>
    <div id="manufacturers_scroller">
        <div u="slides" class="scroll-slides">
            {foreach item=manufacturer from=$manufacturers name=manufacturers_loop}
                <div class="manufacturers_box" id="manufacturer{$manufacturer.manufacturers_id}">
                    <a href="/manufacturer.php?id={$manufacturer.manufacturers_id}">
                        <img src="/images/{$manufacturer.manufacturers_image}" title="{$manufacturer.manufacturers_name}" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this the corresponding css

```
.manufacturers_box {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  img {
    width: 145px;
  }
}
#manufacturers_scroller, .scroll-slides {
  position: relative;
  width: 980px;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Preview is here: http://bierweltweit.kerndter.com/

scrolling works and everything is fine, except that the "slides" take up the whole width, thus only one logo is displayed at a time, i tried around, but i can't find the solution.

Thanks for help!

Regards, Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just fixed it myself by adding ...

```
$SlideWidth: 165
```

:-)